# Threshold an image with lots of noise

Tags: image-processing, filtering, image-segmentation

I have an image with vessels, which comes with a lot of different noise. It's not easy to apply binary threshold as well as Otsu thresholding because these simple methods are not able to extract vessels from greyish background. Greyish background is not uniform.

Is there any way to extract these black vessels from the image?
I know we can apply blurring (e.g Gaussian blur which preserves edges), but in this case loose of vessels' data can happen.
Sorry for the quality of the image, the image comes with a small resolution.

[image: vessels_example]

Tried: gaussian blur with different kernels, binary/Otsu thresholding.
Extracting edges with Sobel kernel, but due to the noise it finds lots of different 'false' edges.
Even if smoothing the image with Gaussian blur.

Comment: You might want to use one of the many vessel detectors. For example look for the Frangi vesselness filter.

Answer (score 0):

After applying intensity thresholding, your segmentation output may appear as follows:

[image]

Numerous artifacts are visible in the output due to the presence of noise in the original image. However, it is worth noting that the noise occupies a relatively small area, so you can utilize an area threshold to
eliminate artifacts of small size.

Here is the reference code for your use.

```
"""
Old_Seg: the binary segmentation output after applying intensity thresholding 
New_Seg: the binary segmentation output after using area thresholding 
th_area: the threshold of the area
height: image height
width: image width
""
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(np.uint8(Old_Seg), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > 0]
output = np.zeros_like(np.uint8(Old_Seg))
cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, 255, -1)
New_Seg= np.zeros((height,width))
for j, contour in enumerate(contours):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area>th_area): // th_are
        New_Seg[y:y+h,x:x+w] = Old_Seg[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```